# Redirecting Domain

Tags: redirect, dns, html

I have two domains. One is [www.nucleation.co.in](http://www.nucleation.co.in) and another [www.nucleation.in](http://www.nucleation.in) 
How can I redirect every link like [www.nucleation.co.in/2012/06/custom-themes-in-gmail.html](http://www.nucleation.co.in/2012/06/custom-themes-in-gmail.html) to [www.nucleation.in/2012/06/custom-themes-in-gmail.html](http://www.nucleation.in/2012/06/custom-themes-in-gmail.html)
Both domains are registered with the same provider.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way on myself. I added a redirect script to every url to take it back to the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your provider should return the 301 response code on any requests to the domain www.nucleation.co.in

To do this, you must contact the your provider. In addition, the provider may not necessarily support this feature, and you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to redirect? 
I think you want  'domain parking'. I too have done something like this, I have two domains for my site, a .com and a .org, I have point both the domains to one site.

If this is your case,
Go to your hosting control panel, check for the domain parking,
if you are using cPanel, there is an icon for that in cPanel.
[check the cPanel document](http://etwiki.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains)

And there is a redirect option too in cPanel, check that too.
Even the domain manager have  an option called 'domain forwarding', check if that suite for your case.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to login your www.nucleation.co.in hosting cpanel and creat index.html then under the code copy and past it in the index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.nucleation.in"></HEAD>
<BODY>
wait a second...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i think it's can help you